# ms access 2007-Reports-Count function

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a total with the count function without getting a running total on the grouping. I need the total number of occupants in a house hold rather than a total number of occupied units. Say i have 4 occupied units and one owned occupied unit. the total comes up with a cumulative of 5. I dont want that running total, I want the total number of people within each occupied unit.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are the names of the fields of interest and what typical values do they contain? Do these fields occur in the Details Section of the Report? And where will you place this total - in the Report Footer?

Comment: Any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working at the report level (as it seems you are), add a group header and/or footer and use the relevant field to define that group.  Instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA010006894.aspx).

If this is a query, you will use `GROUP BY` on the relevant field to break out these totals.  This is used in conjunction with `COUNT`.   These are both aggregate functions, so you'll find them in the same place if using the query-build interface in Access.